# Basic question on units of acceleration due to gravity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, si-units, unit-conversion

In the solved examples I have a question where it is required to find out if a rocket is compatible with the requirement that due to a sensitive payload it should stay below $30g_0$. Does it have something to do with the G-Force? What does it mean?

Also, the rocket is not compatible due to the values $422 \ \text{m}/\text{s}^2$ or $43.1g_0$.
I couldn't understand the unit as unit of acceleration due to gravity ($g$) is $\text{m}/\text{s}^2$. How can there be two values?

Comment: What is 43.1g0 and 30g0 supposed to be?

Comment: It's actually g subscript 0

Comment: I assume that $g_0$ is the acceleration of earth's gravity at its  surface $g_0=9.81$ms$^{-2}$.

Comment: The site standard for writing mathematics is [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and you'll find it very easy to write things like subscripts using it.  People reading your question will also find it easier to understand.

Answer (score 3):

$g_0$ in this case denotes Earth's gravity at the surface, i.e. $g_0 \approx 9.81\,\mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s}^2$. So you can express accelerations either in multiples of $1\,\mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s}^2$, which, for your example, gives you the value of $a = 422\,\mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s}^2$, or in multiples of $g_0$, which gives you $a = 43\,g_0 = 43 \cdot 9.81\,\mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s}^2 = 422\,\mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s}^2$. You can see that these ways of writing the acceleration are really identical. Moreover, expressing your acceleration in multiples of $g_0$ exactly gives you the G-force, which is defined as multiples of Eart's acceleration at the surface.